# Mapping URLs to Site Root with Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I currently have a Django app called "misc" where I have my sites index page, as well as some other pages (most of which contain static information). Right now my **misc/views.py** looks like this:

```
def index(request):     
    return render(request, 'misc/index.html', {})

def why(request):
    return render(request, 'misc/why.html', {})
```

and my urlpatterns in **misc/urls.py** looks like this:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^why/$', views.why, name='why'),
```

and my **main urls.py** looks like this:

```
url(r'^$', include('misc.urls')),
```

so when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I see my index page just fine, however when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/why/ I do not see my why.html page, just a "Page not found" error. Any idea on how I can resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Try to delete $ from your main urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url pattern is matching an empty string:

```
url(r'^$', include('misc.urls')),
```

`^` matches the beginning of a string, and `$` matches the end, so only completely empty strings will work. As Dima points out in the comments, remove the `$` and it will work.